# Django signup page won't display - Produces ImproperlyConfigured at /accounts/signup/ instead

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm working through Django For Beginners by William S. Vincent.

I get this error when I try to access `http://localhost:8000/accounts/signup/`:

```
Internal Server Error: /accounts/signup/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog-dFYK_SP1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog-dFYK_SP1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog-dFYK_SP1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog-dFYK_SP1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog-dFYK_SP1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog-dFYK_SP1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 168, in get
return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog-dFYK_SP1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 133, in get
return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
  File "/Users/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog-dFYK_SP1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 66, in get_context_data
kwargs['form'] = self.get_form()
  File "/Users/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog-dFYK_SP1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 32, in get_form
form_class = self.get_form_class()
  File "/Users/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog-dFYK_SP1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 93, in get_form_class
model = self.get_queryset().model
  File "/Users/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog-dFYK_SP1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py", line 73, in get_queryset
'cls': self.__class__.__name__
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: SignUpView is missing a QuerySet. Define SignUpView.model, SignUpView.queryset, or override SignUpView.get_queryset().
[19/Mar/2019 21:12:04] "GET /accounts/signup/ HTTP/1.1" 500 94136
```

[This is the source code for the particular chapter I'm looking at](https://github.com/wsvincent/djangoforbeginners/tree/master/ch7-blog-app-with-users). As far as I can see, I've copied it exactly. I've even checked for proper indentation and can't see any issues.

Is there anything I should check in relation to this?

Comment: Your generic view needs a model or a queryset and your not giving it neither. Here's the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a typo. In my view I had `from_class` rather than **`form_class`**.

This is how it should be:

```
class SignUpView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'signup.html'
```